# Repostioning a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a view controller with

1. sub view(half the main view size)
2. table view(half the main view size)
3. navigation bar button

On click of button I want the sub view to hide and table view to show with full main view size....It is working fine with below code, but just not for the first time.
For first time when I click bar button it hides the sub view and resizes the table view but does not show the result on screen(works well for rest all time).
If incase I scroll the tableview before clicking navigation bar for the first time it works fines...I think it has something to do with table view loading which I cant make out

**Code**

```
if(isMapVisible==YES) {
    [mapView setHidden:YES];
    [tblView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,
                                 self.view.frame.origin.y+self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height+[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height,
                                 self.view.frame.size.width, 
                                 self.view.frame.size.height-self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height-[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height-self.navigationController.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height)];

    isMapVisible=NO;
} else {
    [mapView setHidden:NO];
    [tblView setFrame:CGRectMake(mapView.frame.origin.x,
                                 mapView.frame.origin.y+mapView.frame.size.height+1,
                                 mapView.frame.size.width,
                                 mapView.frame.size.height)];

    isMapVisible=YES;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    activityCell *cell = (activityCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"activityCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 100;
}
```

Comment: can you shows us more code...this is not sufficient to tell you what went wrong.

Comment: Hard to tell but you could try to force the piece of code which manipulates the frame on the main thread

Comment: try [self.view bringSubviewToFront: self.tblView]... im still unsure of what you are asking though

Comment: Where are you calling your method to change frame?

Comment: on navigationbar button click

Comment: Mins you had problem for first time right?

Answer (score 2):

Call your method like this

```
[self performSelector:@selector(methodToChangeTableViewFrame) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];

-(void)methodToChangeTableViewFrame {

        // Here your code
    if(isMapVisible==YES) {
        [mapView setHidden:YES];
        [tblView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,
                                     self.view.frame.origin.y+self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height+[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height,
                                     self.view.frame.size.width, 
                                     self.view.frame.size.height-self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height-[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height-self.navigationController.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height)];

        isMapVisible=NO;
    } else {
        [mapView setHidden:NO];
        [tblView setFrame:CGRectMake(mapView.frame.origin.x,
                                     mapView.frame.origin.y+mapView.frame.size.height+1,
                                     mapView.frame.size.width,
                                     mapView.frame.size.height)];

        isMapVisible=YES;
    }
}
```